# Dangling goroutine in golang

Tags: go, goroutine

In the following code

1. What happens to `goroutine1`?(at the end of program we have three goroutine `goroutine1` without any functionality)
2. What happens to channel?(when we make a channel in loop it release the previous channel memory? close it? or something else?)

```
func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i += 1 {
        ch := make(chan int)

        // gorutine1
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
            ch <- i
            fmt.Println("gorutine1 end")
        }()

        // gorutine2
        go func() {
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            ch <- i+1000
            fmt.Println("gorutine2 end")
        }()

        fmt.Println("loop", <-ch)
    }

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("main end")
}
```

Run above code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/oIrNMKSwypt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `i=1`, the loop creates two goroutines, and starts waiting to read from the channel. goroutine2 writes first and terminates. The channel is read, and then `i` becomes 2. goroutine1 will wait forever, because nobody will read from the channel again. You create a new channel, and do the same thing. When everything is said and done, you have three instances of goroutine1 waiting to write to three different channels.

Comment: What happens to previous channel when we make a new one? Golang releases its resources? (in `C++` when you `new` an object you must `delete` it o.w. it has memory leak)? what happens here?

Comment: If a channel has no pointers to it, then it will be garbage collected. However, in this case you have goroutine1 still waiting to write to the channel, so the channel is still being used. However the channel is lost because you redefined the channel variable. So both the channel and the goroutine are leaked.